# Easiest way of solving complex simultaneous equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the two following equation:

$(-25+50j)x+(30-45j)y=0$ -(1)

$(3-4j)x-(2-4j)y=106$ -(2)

The answer is $x=68.4-16.8j$ and $y=68-26j$

When i try to substitute the eqn 2 ($x=(106+(2-4j)y)/(3-4j)$) to eqn 1,
it doesn't give me the answer i expected/

Answer (score 1):

Hint: make calculations easier by first factoring a $5$ out -f the first equation:

$$
\begin{align}
-5(1-2j)x+3(2-3j)y &= 0 \\
(3-4j)x-2(1-2j)y &= 106
\end{align}
$$

Eliminate $y$ between the equations by multiplying the first one by $2(1-2j)\,$, the second one by $3(2-3j)\,$, then adding them up:

$$
\begin{align}
-10(1-2j)^2x + 3(3-4j)(2-3j)x = 318(2-3j) \;\;\iff\;\;
 (12 - 11j) x &= 318(2-3j)
\end{align}
$$

Then $\,x=\cfrac{318(2-3j)}{12-11j} \cdot \cfrac{12+11j}{12+11j} = \cfrac{318(57-14j)}{265}=\cfrac{6(57-14j)}{5}=\cfrac{342}{5}-\cfrac{84}{5}\,j\,$.